# Angular v8 add 3rd party styles to component

Tags: angular

My angular component looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css']
})
```

And at the step of compilation via angular-cli I have errors:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'`

How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately no, I have the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Only import your component .scss .css file like that

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

If you creat a files for each import then import like that.

```
  @Component...
  styleUrls: ['./hello.component.scss',
          '../../assets/bs4.css',]
```

It worked in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs4-from-assets

Comment: I need styles just for my one component, not for the whole app.

Comment: Only call css cdn on your component html corner

Comment: I added styles to my component.html at the top of file and removed from component.ts. It fixed errors, but styles are old. So html change didn't do any effect.

Comment: i updated and test it worked for me

Comment: Do you mean add these code to component.scss file? If yes, then it adds styles as global

Comment: Yes only add you project home component style file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204390/discussion-between-ahmetu-and-a-gladkiy).

Comment: @A.Gladkiy I found a solition then uploadted answer

Comment: it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to install this js and CSS which is the proper way

Use this commands for the bootstrap and fontawesome installation

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i font-awesome
// For angular font awesome use
npm i angular-font-awesome
```

Then add there links in styles and scripts in angular.json file

Comment: I need styles just for my one component, not for the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

When building single page application the goal is to keep its size as small as possible, and importing entire library into the component is not the way to do it... In order to use Font Awesome you need to use following [Angular FontAwesome library](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) It supports imports and tree-shaking.

In order to use **Bootstrap 4** you don't need min version - you need **SASS** files, thus you need to:
 1. Install it as a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)
 2. Import **bootstrap** into global styles, I use variables to import:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
```

Import in global styles.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';
@import 'variables.scss'
```